# Nexus Sonatype Dashboard not loading

Tags: apache, svn, jenkins, nexus, sonatype

I have installed nexus sonatype from below url. http://bneijt.nl/blog/post/nexus-on-ubuntu-12.10-installation/ in my EC2 instamce .  I have SVN, Jenkins, nexus in the same instance. Apache is running on port 80. Jenkins is running on 8080. I have configured nexus to 9999 port from nexus.properties files. Nexus is running but I am not able to access the dashboard from browser..

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the port no in  aws security group.